# How to detect if my app window has been snapped using Snaplayouts in Windows 11 - WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-11

I have implemented "Snap View Support" for my application in Windows 11.
Everthing works fine. But I want to check if the window size or its state has been modified using SnapLayout in WPF C#. Is there any API that could help in resoving this?

Assist me with this.